# Unity not work with Quadro NVS 285

Tags: nvidia, additional-drivers

On Ubuntu 16.04 Unity does not work with a nvidia Quadro NVS 285 and the nvidia driver 304.131 installed by the Software Updater. But gnome-session-flashback (metacity) does work.

Thanks.